# How do I center text in bootstrap navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, text, navbar, center

I am trying to center the navbar text and have tried so many things.  None of the previous answers here seem to work.  I am using the template from bootstrap.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light ">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="nav-logo" src="https://site571255.nestifycdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/PoppysQuesadilla-3.png"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active " href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link " href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <!-- <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Text centre means. You have logo and Menu items. All will be centered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to centre all then follow this below code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light" data-toggle="affix">
    <div class="mx-auto d-sm-flex d-block flex-sm-nowrap">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample11" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="navbarsExample11">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

There are more examples here: https://www.codeply.com/go/kTGlK9Axdk